# NoEndPointException() on apache tomcat java- web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tomcat, methods

why i am getting this EndPoint Exception: No endpoint

this is the code:

```java
public org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Output recieveMDMDataInsuredDetails  (org.tempuri.UpdateInsuredDetails_Input l_input) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    if (super.cachedEndpoint == null) {
        logger.info("this is where the endpoint exception occurs:");
        throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
    }
    //this is what the method do
}
```

the object that i am sending to the method : `l_input` - is not null , but still i am falling into the `NoEndPointException()`- why?

Comment: Your condition does not depend on `l_input`, in fact this variable is unused. It seems that `cachedEndpoint`, an attribute of the super class is null. We can't tell why that is the case unless you provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is same as the one mentioned : [java calling web service- No endpoint exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975646/java-calling-web-service-no-endpoint-exception)

InsuredDetailsLocator **locator_MDP**, the variable that carries the endpoint, is not used while calling service. Also, I am doubtful about the space in endpoint URL as mentioned by few others.

Comment: i solved the problem- i had to declare the servise like that :InsuredDetailsSoapStub service= (InsuredDetailsSoapStub)MDP_locator.getInsuredDetailsSoap();